# How to pass the values of the checkboxes to ActionResult in MVC5?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, checkbox

I have an MVC5 app, and in my view, I have a code like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CategoryID, "Category", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-3" })
    <div class="col-md-9">
        @Html.DropDownList("CategoryID", null, "Please select a category", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CategoryID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
<div id="subcatsform" class="form-group" style="visibility:hidden;">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Subcategories, new { @class = "col-md-3 control-label" })
    <div id="subcats" class="col-md-9">

    </div>
</div>
```

Then, I have a JavaScript code which populates the subcategories according to the previously selected category. I achieve it with the following code segment:

```
$(function () {
    $("#CategoryID").on("change", function () {
        var selected_option = $("#CategoryID option").filter(":selected").text();
        $("#subcats").empty();

        if (selected_option != "Please select a category") {
            $("#subcatsform").css("visibility", "visible");

            $.ajax({
                url: "/Home/GetSubcategories",
                dataType: "json",
                data: {
                    cid: $("#CategoryID").val(),
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    $.each(data, function (key, value) {
                        var checkbox = '<input type="checkbox" name="subcategory" value="' + value.id + '"> ' + value.value + '<br />';
                        $("#subcats").append(checkbox);
                    }); 
                }
            });
        }
        else
        {
            $("#subcatsform").css("visibility", "hidden");
        }
    });
});
```

The point is that, until there everything works fine, and for each selected category, I get the list of subcategories correctly and create checkboxes with each one of them, where the name attribute as you can see is equal to `subcategory` and the `value` attribute is equal to the actual id of the subcategory.

What I want to do next, is that I want to get the `value` attributes of the checked checkboxes (meaning selected subcategories), and pass that to my controller. My ActionResult is defined like this:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> RegisterBusiness(BusinessViewModel model)
```

Inside the `BusinessViewModel`, I have a property like this:

```
public virtual ICollection<Subcategory> Subcategories { get; set; }
```

And, finally my `Subcategory` model is defined like this:

```
public class Subcategory
{
    public int SubcategoryID { get; set; }

    public string SubcategoryName { get; set; }

    public string SubcategoryDescription { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Category")]
    [Display(Name = "Category")]
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }

    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
}
```

If someone can help me pass the values of the selected checkboxes into my `RegisterBusiness` ActionResult, and then store them inside my `ICollection<Subcategory> Subcategories` property, I would be glad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your `RegisterBusiness` Action to take a int array named `subcategory`

```
public async Task<ActionResult> RegisterBusiness(BusinessViewModel model, int[] subcategory)
```

The array will automatically catch the selected checkboxes' values.

Now, at postback create `ICollection<Subcategory>` from `string[] subcategory` and assign to Subcategories.

```
using System.Linq;
...
...
ICollection<Subcategory> Subcategories = subcategory.Select(x => new Subcategory { SubcategoryID = x}).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. One question, shouldn't I do a foreach loop, find each subcategory in my database with the id checked, and then return them? Because like the above code I guess it will create a new instances of the subcategories.